# Jenkins job adding new line only when run via jenkins pipeline not stand alone

Tags: json, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline that builds a job that uses powershell to make json based requests.  When I run the job through the pipeline my script adds various line breaks throughout the json. When I run the job by hitting 'rebuild' the script runs without issue.

Output of my request via jenkins pipeline:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/17303495/deployments.json -Method 'POST' -Headers System.Collections.Hashtable -ContentType 'application/json' -Body {
    "deployment": {
        "revision": "Deployment of e0ca4b7
",
        "changelog": "See Release Email Notes",
        "description": "Beginning Deployment of e0ca4b7
",
        "user": "pcort"
    }
}
```

Output of my request via 'rebuild' or manual:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/17303495/deployments.json -Method 'POST' -Headers System.Collections.Hashtable -ContentType 'application/json' -Body {
    "deployment": {
        "revision": "Deployment of e0ca4b7",
        "changelog": "See Release Email Notes",
        "description": "Beginning Deployment of e0ca4b7",
        "user": "pcort"
    }
}
```

Help! This is really weird and breaks my code :) Any ideas would be great!

Jenkins is running ver. 2.46.2 and all plugins are up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with getting the build label.  I'm not entirely sure how it works, maybe someone with more knowledge can inform me, but getting the short git commit `git rev-parse --short HEAD` was leaving a space or new line character at the end of the variable (I was returning this via powershell).  By adding .trim() I cleared this up.